# How to find stale Infinispan / Jboss Cache objects?

Tags: caching, jboss, jboss5.x, infinispan

Subject is the question.

Scenario : Even though there is a logout link, some Users don't properly logout. And they immediately take a new tab and login again. This time a new Cache object is created and the old one is not getting destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can [set a default](http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/5.2/apidocs/org/infinispan/api/BasicCache.html#put%28K,%20V,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) `lifespan` or `maxIdle` to make all entities time out so they don't stay stale for long.

However, to answer your question... You can use the `infinispan-query` module:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-query</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
     </dependency>
```

This uses hibernate search along with apache lucene to query your infinispan cache.

To use this you need to annotate the fields you will search for with `@org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field` and the class with `@org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed`.

Your infinispan cache will also need to be indexed `<indexing enabled="true" indexLocalOnly="false" />` (local or distributed -- see the `indexLocalOnly` property).

And then you can query your cache with something like the following:

```
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder;
import org.infinispan.Cache;
import org.infinispan.query.CacheQuery;
import org.infinispan.query.Search;
import org.infinispan.query.SearchManager;

[...]

public List<YourEntity> searchEntities( String fieldValue ) {
  SearchManager searchManager = Search.getSearchManager( cache );
  QueryBuilder queryBuilder = searchManager.buildQueryBuilderForClass( YourEntity.class ).get();
  // this chain will change depending on what you are querying
  Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onField( "fieldName" ).matching( fieldValue ).createQuery();
  // use either searchManager.getClusteredQuery with local index, or a searchManager.getQuery with clustered index
  CacheQuery cacheQuery = searchManager.getQuery( luceneQuery, YourEntity.class );
  //noinspection unchecked
  return (List)cacheQuery.list();
}
```